# Update duplicate varchars to be unique in SQL database

Tags: sql, database, unique, duplicates

I need to change a database to add a unique constraint on a table column, but the VARCHAR data in it is not unique.

How can I update those duplicate records so that each value is unique by adding a sequential number at the end of the existing data?

e.g. I would like to change 'name' to 'name1', 'name2', 'name3'

Answer (score 7):

Here are 2 examples with using the MS SQL SERVER flavor of sql.

Setup Example:

```
create table test (id int identity primary key, val varchar(20) )
    --id is a pk for the cursor so it can update using "where current of"

-- name a is not duplicated
-- name b is duplicated 3 times
-- name c is duplicated 2 times

insert test values('name a')
insert test values('name b')
insert test values('name c')
insert test values('name b')
insert test values('name b')
insert test values('name c')
```

Sql 2005\2008: ( Computed Table Expression )

```
begin tran; -- Computed table expressions require the statement prior to end with ;

with cte(val,row) as (

    select val, row_number() over (partition by val order by val) row
    --partiton is important. it resets the row_number on a new val
    from test 
    where val in ( -- only return values that are duplicated
        select val
        from test
        group by val
        having count(val)>1
    )
)
update cte set val = val + ltrim(str(row))
--ltrim(str(row)) = converting the int to a string and removing the padding from the str command.

select * from test

rollback
```

Sql 2000: (Cursor example)

```
begin tran

declare @row int, @last varchar(20), @current varchar(20)
set @last = ''
declare dupes cursor
    for
    select val 
    from test 
    where val in ( -- only return values that are duplicated
        select val
        from test
        group by val
        having count(val)>1
    )
    order by val

    for update of val

open dupes
fetch next from dupes into @current
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    --new set of dupes, like the partition by in the 2005 example
    if @last != @current
        set @row = 1

    update test
        --@last is being set during the update statement
        set val = val + ltrim(str(@row)), @last = val
        where current of dupes

    set @row = @row + 1

    fetch next from dupes into @current
end
close dupes
deallocate dupes

select * from test

rollback
```

I rolled back each of the updates because my script file contains both examples. This allowed me to test the functionality without resetting the rows on the table.

Answer (score 1):

Open a cursor on the table, ordered by that column. Keep a previous value variable, initialized to null, and an index variable initialized to 0. If the current value = the previous value, increment the index and append the index to the field value. if the current value <> the previous value, reset the index to 0 and keep the field value as is. Set the previous value variable = the current value. Move on to the next row and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using?

In [Oracle](http://www.psoug.org/reference/OLD/constraints.html) there is a:

NOVALIDATE     Validates changes but does not validate data previously existing in the table

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ENABLE NOVALIDATE UNIQUE;
```

If you are not using Oracle  then check the SQL reference for your respective database.

Comment: We're using FrontBase (which is SQL92 compliant)
I want the existing data to be validated and updated

Comment: I know it is not what he asked, but I did write it before he even tell me he was using FrontBase, that I dont even know. Yet, the principle is same: the database could have something simmilar to the NOVALIDATE clause. Please don't mind the PRIMARY KEY if you think that the type of CONSTRAINT changes anything.

Comment: The question is how to update data that would fail a desired new constraint.  Your answer is to let the database ignore the failure.  While interesting, that doesn't sound like a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another column to it... like

```
update mytable set mycolumn = concat(mycolumn, id) 
            where id in (<select duplicate records>);
```

replace id with whatever column makes mycolumn unique